# How do I create a configuration point in a BUILD file with Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I would like to pass a variable to some of my build rules, e.g. this Webpack step:

```
load("@npm//webpack-cli:index.bzl", webpack = "webpack_cli")

webpack(
  name = "bundle",
  args = [
    "--config",
    "$(execpath webpack.config.js)",
    "--output-path",
    "$(@D)",
  ],
  data = [
    "index.html",
    "webpack.config.js",
    "@npm//:node_modules",
  ] + glob([
    "src/**/*.js",
  ]),
  env = {
    "FOO_BAR": "abc",
  },
  output_dir = True,
)
```

Some builds will be done with `FOO_BAR=abc` and others with a different value. I don't know the full set of possible values!

I don't think that `--action_env` is applicable here since it is not a `genrule`.

I would also like to be able to set a default value in my `BUILD` script.

How can I accomplish this with Bazel?

Answer (score 1):

If you knew the set of values, then the usual tools are `config_setting()` and `select()`, but since you don't know the possible values, then that won't work here.

It looks like `webpack` is actually a `npm_package_bin` or `nodejs_binary` underneath:

```
# Generated helper macro to call webpack-cli
def webpack_cli(**kwargs):
    output_dir = kwargs.pop("output_dir", False)
    if "outs" in kwargs or output_dir:
        npm_package_bin(tool = "@npm//webpack-cli/bin:webpack-cli", output_dir = output_dir, **kwargs)
    else:
        nodejs_binary(
            entry_point = { "@npm//:node_modules/webpack-cli": "bin/cli.js" },
            data = ["@npm//webpack-cli:webpack-cli"] + kwargs.pop("data", []),
            **kwargs
        )
```

and in both cases `env` will do make-variable substitution:

https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/Built-ins.html#nodejs_binary-env

https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/Built-ins.html#npm_package_bin-env

So if you know at least what the variables will be, you can do something like

```
  env = {
    "FOO_BAR": "$(FOO_BAR)",
  },
```

and use `--define=FOO_BAR=123` from the Bazel command line.

`nodejs_binary` has additional attributes related to environment variables:

https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/Built-ins.html#nodejs_binary-configuration_env_vars

https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/Built-ins.html#nodejs_binary-default_env_vars

If the number of environment variables to set, or the name of the environment variable itself, is not known, then you might need to open a feature request with rules_nodejs.